# Hdfs with Kerberos cannot access from remote server

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, hdfs

I configured HDFS with kerberos authencication, I can use my own keytab file to access HDFS on any of the machines within the HDFS cluster. But when I use the same keytab to access HDFS on a remote server outside the HDFS cluster, I cannot access. I received the following error message, by the way, I've copyed the server's config file krb5.conf to the remote machine outside the hadoop cluster.

> java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException:
>   javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by
>   GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed
>   to find any Kerberos tgt)]; Host Details : local host is:
>   "ubuntu/10.235.6.156"; destination host is: "node0":21200;    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:759)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1164)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202)
>     at $Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:628)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
>     at $Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1507)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:783)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileStatus(FileSystem.java:2106)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatusInternal(FileSystem.java:1524)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1503)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1481)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.expandAsGlob(PathData.java:271)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArgument(Command.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArguments(Command.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:190)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:154)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:254)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:304) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate
>   failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided
>   (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:548)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:512)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:596)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1700(Client.java:220)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1213)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1140)   ... 25 more
>   Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed
>   [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism
>   level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]  at
>   com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1300(Client.java:220)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:589)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:586)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:585)
>     ... 28 more Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided
>   (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)    at
>   sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:130)
>     at
>   sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:106)
>     at
>   sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:172)
>     at
>   sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:209)
>     at
>   sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:195)
>     at
>   sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:162)
>     at
>   com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:175)
>     ... 37 more

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I found the reason: when kerberos use AES-256 encryption, you should install JCE. I've installed JCE on the machine within the HDFS cluster, but I didn't realize that the client machine outside the cluster also need JCE. This is the reason why I can access HDFS on the machine within the HDFS cluster, but can't on machine outside the HDFS cluster.